# About SQL and complexity

Tags: sql, database-design, aggregate-functions, data-modeling

I've created a SQL table with a field X and a field DATE. I would like to compute the sum of X where DATE < d. I've two possibilities :

- Create a new field, "sum of X", which represents the sum of X when date < date[field]
- Compute the sum of X "manually", with a SQL request

Is there a method which is always superior ? Or, if not, I assume that it depends on the table size. What is the approximate size that equalizes the two methods ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you elaborate  your last question more?

Comment: Have you tried both? if so what is the code?

Comment: stick with a query instead of adding a field with the stored calculation. you will need to update the stored calculation as time goes on. more maintenance for you if going that route.

Comment: My last question : I assume that the first method is the best for big tables (but I'm not sure) and the second for small tables. So, what is the  limit ?

Comment: I've not tried both, because I've not already the entries.

Comment: The maintenance isn't a problem for me. (I think)

Comment: I agreee with @elvis.  One of the principles of a normalized database is to not store calculated fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a method which is always superior ?

No.  But in general, stick with the simplest solution until you find it doesn't work any more.  The simplest solution in this case is to calculate the derived field each time you need it.

> Or, if not, I assume that it depends on the table size.

Yes. And the number of insertions vs. number of reads.  And whether dates are monotonically increasing or not.  And the space (memory/disk) vs. time (processing power) tradeoff of your system and its requirements.  And probably a good number of other things too.

> What is the approximate size that equalizes the two methods ?

How long is a piece of string?  Too many other variables to answer that.

To repeat: stick with simple until forced to do otherwise.  Maintaining cached values introduces complexity and corner cases: what are your transactional boundaries?  What happens if you add a new row? That presumably triggers a subsequent transaction to detect and update the affected rows.  What happens if you then roll back the original transaction?

That's a *lot* more logic.  With much more potential to go wrong. Stick with [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) until you find you do.

hth.

Comment: Materialized views are another alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will follow your advices :)

Comment: @Catcall: good point.  Materialised views are a possible solution if you need to cache (assuming the dbms supports them).

Answer (score 0):

Don't store calculated field to avoid data inconsistency.
When you have such a question, think about your model and if it should evolv to turn this question obsolete.